# Lambda Expression "NOT IN" C# 4.0

Tags: linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I create this class for a test.
I want to compare to List of the class and get different class between ListA and ListB. In my example the result get only class of ListB.

I do the same thin with list of string and work it

**Class Example**

```
public class FileNode
{
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

List<FileNode> ListA = new List<FileNode>
{
    new FileNode{ Id = 1, Source="a" },
    new FileNode{ Id = 2, Source="b" },
};

List<FileNode> ListB = new List<FileNode>
{
    new FileNode{ Id = 1, Source="a" },
    new FileNode{ Id = 2, Source="b" },
    new FileNode{ Id = 3, Source="c" },
};
List<FileNode> ListAB = ListB.Where(m => !ListA.Contains(m)).ToList();
```

**String example, it's works**

```
List<string> a = new List<string> {"a","b","c","d","e" };
List<string> b = new List<string> {"a","b","c","d" };
List<string> ab = a.Where(m => !b.Contains(m)).ToList();
```

Comment: Despite your tags, you're not using the Entity Framework anywhere in that code - and if you *do* start using EF, it may well behave completely differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well `Contains` is going to call `Equals` on the elements - and may also use `GetHashCode` (I doubt it, but you should override it consistently anyway). So you need to override `Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode()` in `FileNode`. (By default, you'll get reference equality.)

Note that as soon as you start trying to use `Contains` in a query which will execute in the database, it could behave completely different - it wouldn't be looking at your `Equals`/`GetHashCode` methods at that point.